# Derivative of $(log (x))^{x}$

Tags: implicit-differentiation

How can we calculate the value of $ \frac{dy}{dx} (log (x))^{x}$

I tried doing it the following way :

Let $ y= (\log (x))^{x} $

$ \log y = x \log \log (x)$

Then differentiating both sides with respect to $x$ but its not working.

Comment: It should work.

Comment: Saying it's not working doesn't give any information, so it's not really possible to answer your question. That's a valid approach, but we don't know where you're having trouble implementing it.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{d}{dx}\left((\log (x))^x\right)$?

Comment: this type of derivative work out in a convenient manner as following: $ d(\ln y)/dx = (dy/dx) / y$ hence $dy/dx = y * d(\ln y)/dx$. In your case $\ln y = x \log \log x$, which one can differentiate as usual.

Comment: @kmitov It worked. I was making a mistake in applying the chain rule in last step. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\log y=x\log \log x$ Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ you get

$y'/y=\log \log x + x \frac{1}{\log x} \frac{1}{x}$